# XLRD Error(python code to import data from excel to mysql)

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to import all the data from excel(.xlsx) to mysql using Python. I am getting a XLRDError.
Here's my code:

```
import xlrd
import MySQLdb
book=xlrd.open_workbook("Stock Data.xlsx")
sheet=book.sheet_by_name("source")
database=MySQLdb.connect (host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", db="stock_data")
cursor = database.cursor()
adj_close="Adj Close"
query="""insert into stock_data(date,open,high,low,close,volume,adj_close,stock) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    Date = sheet.cell(r,0).value
    Open =sheet.cell(r,1).value
    High =sheet.cell(r,2).value
    Low =sheet.cell(r,3).value
    Close =sheet.cell(r,4).value
    Volume =sheet.cell(r,5).value
    adj_close =sheet.cell(r,6).value
    Stock =sheet.cell(r,7).value
    values=(Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,adj_close,Stock)
    cursor.execute(query,values)
cursor.close()
database.commit()
database.close()
print ""
print "All Done."
```

This is the error that I am getting
[captured as a graphic - sorry about that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmF5n.png)

Please help me to resolve this error
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a sheet named source in your work book?

Comment: Can you double check that the sheet you want to access is called 'source' ? Have you tried referencing by index? for example book.sheet_by_index(0) ?

Comment: create new If the existing is not(about your worksheet)

Comment: thankyou so much..It worked!!